# How does OneDrive select Icon for video? How can I change it

Tags: onedrive, wmv, windows-movie-maker

We have a video, that is uploaded from Windows Moviemaker to OneDrive (Skydrive).  I think it is creating a Windows Media file.

We don't like the Icon used to represent the video.

How does OneDrive select the Icon?

How can I change it?

Are there a better therm than Icon?

Is there something I can edit in the file?

Comment: Is this the file in onedrive as it appears as a folder on your PC?  Or the file in onedrive when you look at it on the web?

Comment: On disk it is the first photo.  (It is a slideshow). One the web it is a "random" photo. BTW, I have tried to replace this photo, and it seems to work (The Icon is also changing)